# Do public content licenses which are not FOSS exist?

Tags: licensing

All non-source-code and/or source-code *public content licenses* I have came across are free or open source (FOSS) which reduces the effect of "copyright" to minimum (although not vanish copyright);

Examples for such *public content licenses* are:

- *Public domain licenses* (FOSS)
- *Creative Commons licenses* (possibly FOSS)
- *GNU General Public License* (FOSS)

While I know that there are *private content licenses* which are not FOSS, I wonder what about public ones;
Do public content licenses which are not FOSS (which increases the effect of "copyright" to maximum) exist?

Comment: What do you mean with the term "public content license"? The Creative Commons NoDerivative (ND) and NonCommercial (NC) licenses are not open-source licenses. Do they qualify?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau - any license that was developed by one entity for the benefit of licensing ANY content by WHATEVER entity (yes the two you mentioned qualify).

Comment: However than we can ask "and what's the license of the license itself" which I fail to answer.

Comment: @guestoscientific You have managed to create two different accounts here, [this one](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/users/21036/guestoscientific) which created this question, and [this one](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/users/21038/guestoscientific) which proposed the edit and created your other question. Please see [the Help Center](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for the procedure to get these merged so you can edit "your own" questions.

Comment: @guestoscientific ...and so you can accept an answer to this question, which is part of the social compact of the site.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there do exist licenses that broadly endeavor to make a work freely available (and often modifiable and redistributable, too) but are not FOSS licenses.

For examples, see the "Nonfree Software Licenses" section on the FSF's [Various Licenses and Comments about Them](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#NonFreeSoftwareLicenses) page, many of which are obviously intended to grant a high degree of freedom but are nevertheless not FOSS for one reason or another. The page usually explains what particular point(s) cause each license to be nonfree.

Comment: There is also the set of badly written licences.And the set of naive licences.